# Is [0, 1) limit point compact as a subspace of R in the usual topology?

Tags: general-topology

I think that since [0,1] is limit point compact, all infinite subspaces of [0,1) has a limit point. Is it wrong?

Comment: No…limit point compact is logically equivalent to compact. It must be closed in the first place. The set {1-1/n} has no limit point there

Comment: (that logical equivalence is true when you are working in metric spaces…there are several other characterizations

Comment: Li Chun Min is right and in $\Bbb R$, Bolzano and Weierstrass tell us that the compact sets are the sets closed and bounded. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Comment: Limit-point compact is also called pre-compact. In general, $S$ is pre-compact iff $\bar S$ is compact.

Answer (score 0):

It is relatively countably compact. This is defined as "all countable subsets of $A$ have limit points in $X$" ( the whole space). These limit points need not lie in $A$, so it's not countably compact as a subspace.

A similar notion exists for relatively sequentially compact. For metric spaces these notions are equivalent to that the closure of $A$ is compact.